# .htaccess redirect with custom url change

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect posts within the same domain.

The old URL structure is

```
/posts/category/340-post-name-with-öäü.html
```

and I want to redirect to

```
/category/post-name-without-id-and-changed-oeaeue
```

(The `340` is an -id which is unique and could also be `2` or `20`.)

**Example:**

```
/posts/onpage/374-fünf-strategien.html
```

to

```
/onpage/fuenf-strategien
```

Is that possible with a `.htaccess` redirect?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Are you having a specific problem with this? Do you have other dierctives in your `.htaccess` file? "The 340 is an -id which is unique and **could also be 2 or 20**" - How is the fact it "could also be 2 or 20" relevant to the question?

Comment: I wasn't able to find other people having the same problem. I included "2 or 20" to let you know that the id isn't meant to solely be a three-digit number.

Comment: So, this is intended to be a many-to-many redirect? Or just a one-to-one? The example you gave can only be a one-to-one since there isn't enough information to generalise it further.

Comment: I am sorry for this misconception - it's intended to be a many-to-many redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the *id* is "unique" then that would seem to be all you need to match.

For example:

```
RedirectMatch ^/posts/category/340- /category/post-name-without-id-and-changed-oeaeue
```

If, however, you are looking for a many-to-many generalised redirect then there's simply not enough information here to perform the redirect in `.htaccess`. For instance, how do you get from `post-name-with` to `post-name-without-id-and-changed` - specifically with regards to the "and-changed" bit?

Any redirect you perform in `.htaccess` can only look at elements of the original request. If the information is not there to begin with (in some form) then you can't magically use it in the target of the redirect without hardcoding it. (If you have access to the server-config then you can configure `RewriteMap`s - essentially a "lookup-table" to help with the redirect. But otherwise, `.htaccess` alone does not have this ability.)

If you have many redirects of this nature then you are better off performing the redirect in your server-side code (application logic), instead of `.htaccess`.

**UPDATE:** From your second example: `/posts/onpage/374-fünf-strategien.html` to `/onpage/fuenf-strategien`. Again, there's no logical process to get from `fünf` to `fuenf` without hardcoding the replacement.

If there is a finite series of replacements, eg. `öäü` to `oeaeue` and `fünf` to `fuenf` then you could apply these in `.htaccess` *before* removing the `.html` extension, ID, and changing the URL-path, etc. However, if you are adding arbitray text on a per URL basis (eg. the `and-changed` bit above) then you are back to doing this one URL at a time.